# JEditorPane filling all available space in JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, layout-manager, jeditorpane

I'm using a `JEditorPane` inside a `JPanel` which I've called my `contentPane` in the example below. The content pane is inside a `JScrollPane`. I would like the editor pane to fill as little space as possible (to just contain it's text) and the rest of the space available in the content pane be left empty to the bottom, and on either side. If the text gets too large, the editor pane will grow, and eventually the scroll pane will create scroll bars to browse through all of the content. However, instead of the editor pane only taking up its preferred size (which is the size of the text it contains) it fills up the entire content pane which fills the entire view port of the scroll pane. Here's some example code to demonstrate my problem:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ScrollPaneExample extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ScrollPaneExample();
    }
    public ScrollPaneExample() {
        super("ScrollPaneExample");

        setSize(400, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane("text/plain", "");
        editorPane.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            editorPane.setText(editorPane.getText() + "Hello World\n");

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        contentPane.add(editorPane);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(contentPane);

        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

When run, this is what the window looks like:

[image: Example]

By the yellow background, we can see that the editor pane is taking up all the space. Here is a (Photoshopped) example of what I want the layout to look like:

[image: Desired]

The blue background represents the content pane, and the yellow represents the editor pane.

**Edit:** In my working program, there is more than just an editor pane in the `contentPane`. This is why I am using a `BoxLayout` instead of a `FlowLayout` for the `contentPane`; because the vertical page-flow layout is desired.

Comment: How is the size to be determined? Do you want it this exact size (meaning to fit five hello worlds)? Do you want it a specific size? Do you want it size based on dynamic text?

Comment: @peeskillet The editor pane should dynamically change size based on the text. To fit whatever text is entered.

Comment: You want the view to in the scroll pane to dynamically size (so basically the whole scroll pane - which kinda defeats the prupose of a scroll pane)? Or the view to stay the same but scrolls added? In the latter case, what is to determine the initial size, the content of five hello worlds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a `FlowLayout` for the content pane. `BorderLayout` won't respect preferred size and will stretch the component to fit. See more about layout managers at [Laying out Components Withing a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

If you want to set an initial size for the editor pane, just like with any other component that is [`Scollable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Scrollable.html), you can override [`getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Scrollable.html#getPreferredScrollableViewportSize%28%29) to set the size for the scroll pane view (when the component is added)

Also you should be adding the editor to the scroll pane, not the panel. Doing the latter, the editor will not be scrollable in the scroll pane.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ScrollPaneDemo extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ScrollPaneDemo();
    }

    public ScrollPaneDemo() {
        super("ScrollPaneExample");

        setSize(400, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane("text/plain", "") {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
                return new Dimension(200, 200);
            }
        };
        editorPane.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            editorPane.setText(editorPane.getText()
                    + "Hello World Hello World\n");
        }

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(editorPane);

        add(scrollPane);

        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

> In my working program, there is more than just an editor pane in the contentPane. This is why I am using a BoxLayout instead of a FlowLayout for the contentPane; because the vertical page-flow layout is desired.

The BoxLayout is the problem. You need to set a maximum size for the editor pane. Or just get rid of the BoxLayout all together. FlowLayout or GridBagLayout will respect the preferred size

---

**UPDATE 2**

Here is an example using GridBagLayout that may more suitable for your "expanding" editor.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.Timer;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ScrollPaneExample extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ScrollPaneExample();
    }
    public ScrollPaneExample() {
        super("ScrollPaneExample");

        setSize(400, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        //getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        final JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane("text/plain", "") {
        };

        editorPane.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            editorPane.setText(editorPane.getText() + "Hello World\n");

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        contentPane.add(editorPane, gbc);

        gbc.gridy++;
        contentPane.add(new JButton("Button"), gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        contentPane.add(new JButton("Button"), gbc);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(contentPane);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);

        add(scrollPane);

        setVisible(true);

        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                editorPane.setText(editorPane.getText() + "Hello World\n");
                setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You've misunderstood me. In my example, the scroll pane is actually irrelevant. I would like the scroll pane to fill the entire window (400x400), but the content INSIDE the `JPanel` to fit to its smallest size. The reason I'm putting the `JEditorPane` inside a `JPanel` instead of just adding it to the scroll pane directly is because in my working program, there is more components inside the `contentPane` than just the editor pane. Perhaps I've made it confusing my calling the `JPanel` inside the scroll pane a `contentPane`, which is ambiguous with the top-level "content pane" of the Window.

Comment: Gotcha. The BoxLayout is the problem. You need to set a maximum size for the editor pane. Or just get rid of the BoxLayout all together. FlowLayout or GridBagLayout will respect the preferred size

Comment: Setting the maximum size of the editor pane as its preferred size was how I first thought to solve the problem. The issue here is that when more text is added to the editor pane, its preferred size will automatically change, but its maximum size wont. And adding a `ComponentListener` does not work, since it only listens to the size changing, not the preferred size. See my editor for why a `BoxLayout` is desirable. Perhaps `GridBagLayout` may be the solution, I'll take a look.

Comment: That's what I was asking you in the comment in the original post. But you never answered. I dunno, that's an odd requirement if you ask me. What's wrong with a scroll pane. Why would you want the editor to keep messing with the layout of all the other components?

Comment: Please see my **UPDATE 2**. Maybe that's what you're looking for

Comment: Looks good, I usually avoid using the `GridBagLayout` just because it complicates things like this very easily, but in this case its entirely necessary over the `BoxLayout`.